# Can't start useraccount / no GUI terminal

Tags: terminal, user-accounts

When I am in the startmenu of Ubuntu 12.04 I can not start in my own account and I don't see any error messages.

I try to use my account and then I return to the original start menu. I can start in the guest account, but then I can not use my own files. Also, in the guest account, I don't have any rights to change my own account.

How can I repair that?

I can get into the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

The problems started after I installed updates in the Update Manager program, but I can not remember what updates.

Before that I also experienced a problem with starting a terminal. I saw the terminal window flash on the screen and then it vanished. No matter which terminal I tried to use.

I have a Dell Inspiron N7010, Intel(R) HD Graphics, on x64 based PC, Intel Pentium CPU P6100, 2.00 GHz, 1999 MHz, 2 core's 2 logical processors BIOS Dell A11 31.03.2011, SMBIOS 2.6 Mem 4 Gb, Total virtual mem 7,6 Gb

The Ubuntu / Linux versions I see in the boot screen are:

`GNU-GRUB version 1.99-21ubuntu3`

In the right corner below it says: 
`debian The Universal Operating System.`

The versions are:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae (recovery mode)
- Memory test (memtest 86+)
- Memory test (memtest 86+, serial console 115200)
- Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-10-generic (on /dev/sda5)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-10-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda5)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic (on /dev/sda5)
- Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.38-8-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda5)

The 2.6.38-10 and 2.6.38-8 versions both work, but in those versions I can not approach my own files.

#### Sunday May 27 2012

Just now I received a lot of new software from Ubuntu and thanks to that (I think) I am now able to use my useraccount in Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm relieved!

The only thing still not working is starting a GUI terminal, like Byobu or another terminal. I only get to see a quick flash on my screen and then it's gone.

In answer to your suggestion to try the `less etc.` command I received the following:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 27: .:Can't open /usr/bin/byobu-launch
/home/rita/.xsession-errors (END)
```

and that is all.

Maybe I'm missing some file or package or other. I searched in my entire filesystem for that file, but no luck, it was'nt there. No idea why.

#### Thursday May 31 2012

hope my internet connection will stay up long enough for new info:
I executed again the `less etc.` command and got the following:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
gnome-session[1623]: WARNING: Failed to start app: Unable to start application: Failed to execute child process "gnome-power-manager" (No such file or directory)
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject

** (nautilus:1728): WARNING **: Can not get _NET_WORKAREA

** (nautilus:1728): WARNING **: Can not determine workarea, guessing at layout
failed to create drawable
failed to create drawable
** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1200004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
/usr/bin/indicator-weather:1932: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_window_thaw_toplevel_updates_libgtk_only: assertion `private->update_and_descendants_freeze_count > 0' failed
  gtk.main()

(gnome-shell:1710): folks-WARNING **: Failed to find primary PersonaStore with type ID 'eds' and ID 'system'.
Individuals will not be linked properly and creating new links between Personas will not work.
The configured primary PersonaStore's backend may not be installed. If you are unsure, check with your distribution.
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x2200003 (Transmissi)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1200004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x2200003 (Transmissi) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1200004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1200004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x260002e (http://www) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1200004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!

(nm-applet:1724): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple: assertion `dest_width > 0' failed
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x2200003 (Transmissi) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1200004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1200004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x1200004 (Desktop) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: CurrentTime used to choose focus window; focus window may not be correct.
/home/rita/.xsession-errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if you can read `/home/replacethiswithyourusername/.xsession-errors` from a text console (what you seem to call 'terminalmode'). You can use the `less` application to read that file:

```
less /home/replacethiswithyourusername/.xsession-errors
```

Navigate through the file's text with your cursor keys and/or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, <kbd>PageDown</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>.
Press <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit the 'less' application and return to your shell prompt.

It might contain relevant information as to why your GUI-session fails to start.

Also, in the 'Graphical Greeter', the graphical interface where you'd normally authenticate with your username and password to enter your GUI-session, there should be an option to choose a different 'Login Session'.

It could list things like 'Ubuntu Classic' or options with 'Unity' in its name.

Try selecting different options there before authenticating with your username and password. One or the other might work...